# dataTables' JS variable not being updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```
//edit function
$('#dataTable tbody').on( 'click', '.am-text-secondary', function () {
    //get the id of selected row
    var rowData = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
    var updateId = rowData.id;
    if(!updateId)
        return;     
    console.log("updateId_1:"+updateId);
    $.ajax({
        url: "getDataById.do?id="+updateId, 
        success: function (data) {
            //assign the editModal
        }                   
    });
    $('#editModal').modal({
        relatedTarget: this,
        width:600,
        onConfirm: function(options) {  
            console.log("updateId_2:"+updateId); 
            $.ajax({
            //do something
            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

When first trigger edit function, the updateId_1 and updateId_2 shows 26.

But then second trigger, updateId_1 shows 27, updateId_2 still shows 26...

Where's the problem?

Comment: What plugin are you using for modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `ajax` performs an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request.

You need to set `async` property to `false` to execute the statements in that order it is defined.

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

```
$.ajax({
    url: "getDataById.do?id="+updateId, 
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        //assign the editModal
    }                   
});
$('#editModal').modal({
    relatedTarget: this,
    width:600,
    onConfirm: function(options) {  
        console.log("updateId_2:"+updateId); 
        $.ajax({
        //do something
        }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: yeap,have fixed the problem!